# How to trigger workflow by updating splistitem in console program?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

My list item has a workflow which it will send an email if the approval status is submitted. I decided to create a timer job to run every day for sending a reminder (just update the list item to trigger workflow).

It does not work when I trying to  `spitem.Update();`

However, if I try to update this item in sharepoint UI, the workflow will be triggered normally.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the code below when updating item.

SPSite.WorkflowManager.Dispose();

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

SPListItem.Update() not starting workflow.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/malag/2008/07/11/splistitem-update-not-starting-workflow/

Comment: SPSite.WorkflowManager.Dispose(); will stop my code :(